# JS - Prime numbers script - explanation

Tags: javascript, numbers

I'm learning JS and stumbled upon a script to output the prime numbers < 100 . But I'm not sure I fully understood how it works. If somebody could explain it, I would be glad. :)

So here it is:

```
for (var counter = 0; counter <= 100; counter++)
{
    for (var i = 2; i <= counter-1; i++)
        if (counter%i === 0) break;
    if(i === counter)
        console.log(counter);
}
```

Comment: This may help: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp -- Understanding for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how much JavaScript you know, so some of this might be really basic.

First, remember that a prime number is one whose only factors are 1 and itself.

So the first line says it loops from 0 to 100, with `counter` as the variable holding this number.

The next line `for (var i = 2; i <= counter-1; i++)` loops from 2 to `counter`-1 (notice it excludes 1 and `counter`) and uses `i` to hold this number.

Next, `if (counter%i === 0) break;` tests whether `counter` is divisible by `i`: the remainder operator `%` returns the remainder (like from long division), e.g. `11 % 3` will return `2` because 11 divided by 3 gives 3 remainder 2; if the remainder `counter % i` is `0` (`===` is a stricter equality than `==`, but that's a different answer altogether) that means that `counter` is divisible by `i` and so is not prime. The `break` statement tells it to exit the innermost loop (that is, the loop over `i`), so the program increments `counter` and goes on.

If the previous line did not break for any value of `i`, then `counter` is prime — specifically, at the end of the loop body, `i` is incremented (now equal to `counter`), the statement `i <= counter-1` evaluates to false, and the loop ends. So now `i === counter` is true, so `console.log(counter)` shows this value in the console.

Comment: Thanks! This explained the counter-1 of the 2nd Loop more visually for me.

Answer (score 1):

Primes are by definition only divisible by themselves and 1.
The outer loop `for var(counter = 0; ...)` loops through the numbers from 0 to 100.
The inner loop `for (var i = 2; ...)` then tries to divide the outer number by every number between 2 and the counter's value. If any of them divide the number without a remainder the loop is broken. That's the `if (counter%i === 0) break;` line.
If we broke out of loop and `i === counter`, it's a prime, else it's not - by definition.

Comment: Thank you. The counter-1 part somehow seemed kind of tricky to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* For every number from 0 to 100, do the following: */
for (var counter = 0; counter <= 100; counter++)
{
    /* Loop through values from 2 to 1 before the counter. */
    for (var i = 2; i <= counter-1; i++) {
        /* if the remainder of dividing counter by the current value of `i` is zero,
         * we know we don't have a prime, so break out of the loop:
         */
        if (counter%i === 0) break; 
    }
    /* If the loop completed and `i` is equal to the counter, that means counter is not
     * divisible by anything except for 1 and itself, making it prime
     */
    if(i === counter)
        console.log(counter);
}
```